# Calculating the eigenvalues of a diagonalisable linear operator $L$.

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

I want to calculate the eigenvalues of some diagonalisable linear operator $L$ in some basis $B$ with the following transformation matrix.

$$
[L]_B = \begin{bmatrix} 3+\frac{1}{2}i & -\frac{1}{2}-2i &0 \\ \frac{1}{2}+2i &3+\frac{1}{2}i & 0 \\  0 & 0 & 1-i
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I know that the trace of any diagonalisable operator $L$ is equal to the sum of its eigenvalues independent of what basis we choose. So in this case, the sum of eigenvalues is 7. However, I want to calculate the individual values of the eigenvalues. When trying to determine the roots of the characteristical polynomial, I find a very difficult polyniomal that I can't solve by hand. I was thinking that there has to be a smarter way to solve this problem. Could anyone help me?

Thanks for your time,

K. Kamal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your matrix is block-diagonal, which makes computation easy in this case.  In particular, we know that $1-i$ will be the eigenvalue corresponding to eigenvector $(0,0,1)$, and the remaining eigenvalues are simply the eigenvalues of the submatrix
$$
\pmatrix{3+ \frac 12 i & - \frac 12 - 2i\\
\frac 12 + 2i & 3 + \frac 12 i}
$$
Perhaps you could take it from there.

Comment: I think that that is what I was missing. If $1-i$ is an eigenvalue, that makes  $1+i$ an eigenvalue as well. But since the sum of the eigenvalues needs to be 7 and we have a $3x3$ matrix, the last eigenvalue needs to be $5$, if I'm correct.

Comment: @K.Kamal It is not necessarily the case that $1 + i$ is an eigenvalues.  Because this is a matrix with complex (non-real) entries, it is possible to have eigenvalues that do not come in conjugate pairs.

Comment: @K.Kamal However, it does appear that, in this case, you have [arrived at the correct answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigenvalues+%7B%7B3%2Bi%2F2,+-1%2F2+-+2i%7D,%7B1%2F2+%2B+2i,3+%2B+i%2F2%7D%7D)